# How do i add for each toggle button a int value ? [flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart

I have three toggle buttons, how do i add for  each toggle button a int  value ?

```
 ToggleButtons(
   children: [
     Text('5 '),
     Text('6'),
     Text('7'),
   ],
   onPressed: (int index) {
     setState(() {
       for (int buttonIndex = 0;
         buttonIndex < isSelected2.length;
         buttonIndex++) {
         if (buttonIndex == index) {
           isSelected2[buttonIndex] = true;
         } else {
           isSelected2[buttonIndex] = false;
         }
       }
     });
   },
   isSelected: isSelected2,
 ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not really clear, but I assume that if the user presses e.g. the button with the text "5" this value should be applied to an integer variable which you would use anywhere else, this you could implemented like this:

```
...
int _choice;
...

ToggleButtons(
    children: [
        Text('5'),
        Text('6'),
        Text('7'),
    ],
    onPressed: (int index) {
        setState(() {
            isSelected2[index] = !isSelected2[index];
                switch(index){
                    case 0:
                        _choice = 5;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        _choice = 6;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        _choice = 7;
                        break;
                } 
            }
        );
    },
    isSelected: isSelected2,
),
```

Comment: thank you, How do i select single button if the button has multiple cases?

Comment: I don't understand your question